# Visual Studio 2022 & ASP.NET Core 6 : show connections

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an issue where I'm running out of worker_connections in NGINX and I wanted to do a stress test on my app to make sure all connections are good and not building up somewhere (it's a huge project).

How can I see how many current connections are made to the app? Either by database, client, httpClient requests, etc?

I’m running this on AWS EB. 8 t2.small instances at a rate of 500 requests per second on the load balancer.

Comment: How did you configure ASP.NET Core with nginx? Similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-7.0 or with your own customization? Discussions cannot start with that key information. If you want to learn more about runtime status, take a full memory dump and analyze it, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-dump

Comment: I’m running this on AWS EB. 8 t2.small instances at a rate of 500 requests per second on the load balancer.

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.